# Make a string based on timeframe

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how to make a string based on the current time, and time ranges in Python. So, if it's between 8am and 11am, for Python to identofy what time it is, and automatically return a "breakfast" string; and if its between 11am to 4pm --> return a lunch string

Comment: did you look already at the datetime module.
or if you don't mind installing third party packages you might look at arrow 
https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: That's interesting. Did you have...a question?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please clarify what your *specific* question is?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please, try to be clear when asking and bring some examples that you tried before.
Getting the time is easy as:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("Current Time =", current_time)
```

You can see more information about datetime module [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/current-time)

So, current_time brings a string with the time. To select minutes or hours you need to pick up the position that they're at.

For example:

```
myTime = "12:34:56"
seconds = myTime[-2:]
print(seconds)

56
```

For more examples on slicing strings, [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/slice)

You want integers instead of strings?

```
seconds = int(seconds)
```